# Error al ejecutar kivy en virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Amigos resulta que tengo ubuntu 18.04 y tengo instalado python 3.6 en una virtualenv donde tengo opencv, con mas programas pero ahora que me resulta un error y es el siguiente la verdad no se que pasa o donde surge el error les agradesco sus ayudas amigos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descarga xsel y xclip con el gestor de paquetes de Ubuntu.